# Splitting a nested string keeping quotation marks

Tags: java, regex, string

I am working on a project in Java that requires having nested strings.

For an input string that in plain text looks like this:

> This is "a string" and this is "a \"nested\" string"

The result must be the following:

```
[0] This
[1] is
[2] "a string"
[3] and
[4] this
[5] is
[6] "a \"nested\" string"
```

**Note** that I want the `\"` sequences to be kept.
I have the following method:

```
public static String[] splitKeepingQuotationMarks(String s);
```

and I need to create an array of strings out of the given `s` parameter by the given rules, without using the *Java Collection Framework* or its derivatives.

I am unsure about how to solve this problem.
Can a regex expression be made that would get this solved?

**UPDATE based on questions from comments**:

- each unescaped `"` has its closing unescaped `"` (they are balanced)
- each escaping character `\` also must be escaped if we want to create literal representing it (to create text representing `\` we need to write it as `\\`).

Comment: @Turtle: Not always. It will split the `nested` string too.

Comment: even if you split on a space?

Comment: That isn't a regular language. You need features beyond ordinary regular expressions. Look-arounds extend regex to beyond regular languages, but since this sounds like a school assignment, the goal might be to get you to write a lexer (lexical analyzer).

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing - writing a Lexer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse string with whitespace and quotation mark (with quotation mark retained)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607051/parse-string-with-whitespace-and-quotation-mark-with-quotation-mark-retained)

Comment: I don't think so - that question doesn't mention nested strings.

Comment: Can we assume that string is always balanced? Like each `"` has its proper closing `"`?

Comment: Yes. At least the most outer string.

Comment: Do the quotes inside a nested quote have the `\"` or is it a plain `"`?

Comment: Is it possible that inside quote text will end with ``\``? I mean, what if we want to quote ``path = dir1\dir2\``? If I write `"path = dir1\dir2\"` then last `\"` would represent escaped `"` which will prevent quote from being properly closed here. Can we assume that each ``\`` (at least inside quotes) also requires escaping with another ``\``?

Comment: The nested quotes must have `\"` (with an escape-character). Also, the escape-character itself must be escaped.

Comment: Does it mean you need a `String[]` variable at the end?

Comment: Yes. This would be trivial if I am allowed to use the _Java Collection Framework_, but this is not the case. Thank you for the updated answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|\S+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rQ8tW7/1)

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/XvVAP9):

```
String str = "This is \"a string\" and this is \"a \\\"nested\\\" string\""; 
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"|\\S+");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

**Explanation**:

- `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` - a double quote that is followed with any 0+ characters other than a `"` and `\` (`[^"\\]`) followed with 0+ sequences of any escaped sequence (`\\.`) followed with  any 0+ characters other than a `"` and `\`
- `|` - or...
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace characters

**NOTE**

[@Pshemo's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292591/splitting-a-nested-string-keeping-quotation-marks/36292725?noredirect=1#comment60211826_36292725) - `"\"(?:\\\\.|[^\"])*\"|\\S+"` (or [`"\"(?:\\\\.|[^\"\\\\])*\"|\\S+"`](https://regex101.com/r/aN9fH3/1) would be more correct) - is the same expression, but much less efficient since it is using an alternation group quantified with `*`. This construct involves much more backtracking as the regex engine has to test each position, and there are 2 probabilities for each position. My *unroll-the-loop* based version will match chunks of text at once, and is thus much faster and reliable.

**UPDATE**

Since `String[]` type is required as output, you need to do it in 2 steps: count the matches, create the array, and then re-run the matcher again:

```
int cnt = 0;
String str = "This is \"a string\" and this is \"a \\\"nested\\\" string\""; 
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"|\\S+");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    cnt++;
}
System.out.println(cnt);
String[] result = new String[cnt];
matcher.reset();
int idx = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    result[idx] = matcher.group(0);
    idx++;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/F212Qz)

Comment: WTF ...! How did you do that ..! +1

Comment: @Shafizadeh I added the explanation, and now giving the comp to my nagging wife :)

Comment: `Pattern.compile("\"(?:\\\\.|[^\"])*\"|\\S+");` should probably also work.

Comment: @Pshemo: I think that unroll-the-loop based regex is much more efficient than a non-unrolled one. Just compare them at regex101.com, and you will feel the difference. You may even  test in Java. I am sure my version is  much less stack overflow error prone than your version with alternation group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Interesting. I should probably read some book about regex and its optimization.

Comment: How do you get from this regex to an array?

Comment: @erickson: It is easy: just add a `List<String>` and add matches into it... I have added a code example.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `List` is not allowed: *"without using the Java Collection Framework or its derivatives."*

Comment: @erickson: **You** asked for a list as an output.

Comment: No I didn't. What are you talking about?

Comment: Then I do not get you.

Comment: Where did I lose you? The OP asked for an array result, and his constraints don't permit use of the Java Collections Framework. You've provided a partial answer, and my initial comment was intended to challenge you to address this aspect as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and a step-by-step explanation of the regex. This works flawlessly. Sorry I caused this confusion about the _Java Collection Framework_, this is because I edited the question some time after this answer was posted. I created an array by counting the `matcher.find()` **true** results, did a `matcher.reset();`, and then doing the `matcher.find()` and `matcher.group(0)` in a _for-loop_ and adding these results to the array. This may not be very efficient, but I don't see another way to create an array.

Comment: I have been working on the implementation of the same idea. I updated the answer with [**this demo**](http://ideone.com/F212Qz)

Comment: Thank you. This is the same as what I made a few moments ago. Marked as accepted answer.

Comment: Oracle [proposes](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/05/13/oracle_proposes_to_deliver_of_java_9_sdk_on_september_22nd_2016/) to deliver Java 9 SDK on September 22nd, 2016, and there is going to be a [`Stream<MatchResult> results()`](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) method that might be handy for obtaining the count of matches and matches themselves. Not sure a stream can be used in this scenario though.

Comment: [One more attemp to get rid of two matchers](http://ideone.com/zQBT4c). Not tested on more strings, just added spaces at the start and end.

Answer (score 7):

Another regex approach that works uses a negative lookbehind: "words" (`\w+`) *OR* "*quote followed by anything up to the next quote that ISN'T preceded by a backslash*", and set your match to "global" (don't return on first match)

```
(\w+|".*?(?<!\\)")
```

[see it here](https://regex101.com/r/vO3iN9/1).

Comment: That's a nice pattern, +1

Comment: But how do you go from a token regex to an array of matches, without using a `List`? The `split` APIs use a delimiter expression, not a token expression.

Comment: @erickson: not sure what you mean..?

Comment: This is a wrong solution that will fail if there is an escaped ``\`` right before a `"`. **One can't parse such grammars with lookaheads like this**.

Comment: The OP says, "I need to create an array of strings out of the given s parameter" How do you get from the regex to the array?

Comment: There's no requirement to escape \

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked great until a string with the `=` character came up. It skips the `=` for some reason.

Comment: @erickson ``There's no requirement to escape \`` now it officially is, at least inside quotes (I asked OP about it). BTW if I remember correctly you ware trying to create ``\`` (inside code sample). To do so you need to surround \ with two `\`` (from bot sides) like `\`\`\\`\``.

Comment: Thank you for noticing. :D Noted.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method that does not use a regex:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SplitKeepingQuotationMarks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "This is \"a string\" and this is \"a \\\"nested\\\" string\"";
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitKeepingQuotationMarks(pattern)));
    }

    public static String[] splitKeepingQuotationMarks(String s) {
        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder last = new StringBuilder();
        boolean inString = false;
        boolean wasBackSlash = false;

        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isSpaceChar(c) && !inString) {
                if (last.length() > 0) {
                    results.add(last.toString());
                    last.setLength(0); // Clears the s.b.
                }
            } else if (c == '"') {
                last.append(c);
                if (!wasBackSlash)
                    inString = !inString;
            } else if (c == '\\') {
                wasBackSlash = true;
                last.append(c);
            } else
                last.append(c); 
        }

        results.add(last.toString());
        return results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);
    }
}
```

Output:

> [This, is, "a string", and, this, is, "a \"nested\" string"]

Comment: `import java.util.ArrayList;` -> "without using the Java Collection Framework or its derivatives."