# RegEx of underscore delimited string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with 5 pieces of data delimited by underscores:

```
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE
```

I want a different regex for each component.
The regex needs to return just the one component.
For example, the first would return just AAA, the second for BBB, etc.

I am able to parse out AAA with the following:

```
^([^_]*)?
```

I see that I can do a look-around like this to find:

```
(?<=[^_]*_).*
BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE
```

But the following can not find just BBB

```
(?<=[^_]*_)[^_]*(?=_)
```

Comment: what is your question please!

Comment: and is it Java or JS? 'cause `(?<=[^_]*_).*` wouldn't work in Java.

Comment: You really don't want to split the string first?

Comment: ?  >> I want a different regex for each component.
I would like to get 5 separate regex expressions, one to find each of the five components with no other text  I am configuring a tool based on Java that accepts only a single regex statement.

Comment: Does it have to match the whole expression or can you use a capturing group?

Comment: It needs to match the whole expression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a nested string keeping quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292591/splitting-a-nested-string-keeping-quotation-marks)

Comment: are the strings between the "_" constant length?

Comment: This is arguably not what Regexes are for (especially considering Java Regexes don't support variable-length look-behind), and **objectively** much more **simply** achieved using `str.split("_")` (which would coincidentally also be much more readable).

Comment: @ccjmne Java supports variable-length lookbehinds but not infinite lookbehinds.

Comment: Ah! Wow, I was really convinced it wasn't a thing in Java. Thanks @revo

Answer (score 0):

Mixing lookbehind and lookahead

```
^([^_]+)? // 1st
(?<=_)[^_]+ // 2nd
(?<=_)[^_]+(?=_[^_]+_[^_]+$) // 3rd
(?<=_)[^_]+(?=_[^_]+$) // 4th
[^_]+$ // 5th
```

<strike>Just if the lengths of the strings beetween the "_" are known it can be like this</strike>

1st match

```
^([^_]+)?
```

2nd match

```
(?<=_)\K[^_]+
```

3rd match

```
(?<=_[A-Za-z]{3}_)\K[^_]+
```

4th match

```
(?<=_[A-Za-z]{3}_[A-Za-z]{3}_)\K[^_]+
```

5th match

```
(?<=_[A-Za-z]{3}_[A-Za-z]{3}_[A-Za-z]{3}_)\K[^_]+
```

each {3} is expressing the length of the string beetween "_"

Comment: Unfortunately, the length of the strings can vary.

Comment: @AndresDLRG - the 2nd one should be (?<=^(?:[^_]+)_)[^_]+

Answer (score 0):

If your string is always uses underscores, you might use 1 regex to capture your values in a capturing group by repeating the pattern of what is before (in this case NOT an underscore followed by an underscore) using a quantifier which you can change like `{3}`.

This way you can specify using the quantifier how many times you want to repeat the pattern before and then capture your match. For your example string `AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE` you could use `{0}`, `{1}`,`{2}`,`{3}` or `{4}`

[`^(?:[^_\n]+_){3}([0-9A-Za-z]+)(?:_[^_\n]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/0Hr6iO/1)

That would match:

- `^` Assert position at start of the line
- `(?:[^_\n]+_){3}` In a non capturing group `(?:`, match NOT and underscore or a new line one or more times `[^_\n]+` followed by an underscore and repeat that n times (In this example n is 3 times)
- `([0-9A-Za-z]+)` Capture your characters in a group using for example a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (or use `[^_]+` to match not an underscore but that will also match any white space characters)
- `(?:_[^_\n]+)*` Following after your captured values, repeat in a non capturing group matching an underscore,  NOT and underscore or a new line one or more times and repeat that pattern zero or more times to get a full match
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line